# Do child classes inherit parent constants and if so how do I access them?

Tags: php, class, oop

Questions says it all really.

I have constants defined in my parent class.  I have tried `$this->CONSTANT_1` but it's not working.

```
class MyParentClass
{
    const CONSTANT_1=1;
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass
{
 // I want to access CONSTANT_1  

}
```

Comment: Try $my_child_class_instance::CONSTANT_1

Comment: You have defined a *class constant* with `const`, not a *constant* which uses the `define` keyword. Thus, your *class constant* belongs to the class, not an instance of the class. Logically, that is why `$this->CONSTANT_1` failed. `$this` only has access to *instance* members, and your class constant is not part of that family. You want to use is `self::` instead of `$this`.

Comment: **Note**: If you use an `Interface` to centralize the definition of class constants, you cannot subsequently override them in child classes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: @LauriElias Your suggestion will not work because a basic reference to a class level member using the scope resolution operator (`::`) must not be be proceed by a dollar sign. `MyParentClass::`, not `$MyParentClass::` ;-) Using the `self` keyword in the child class is the way to go, especially since in PHP 7.1+ class constants can have visibility modifiers.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Your necromantic inclinations aside, it does work: https://www.tehplayground.com/xEnBzy6fxprF4THw

Comment: @LauriElias If it can work, I would need to see a test. If it does work, it may be a bug. In any case, it would not be *good* syntax. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php. Why? You have not assigned the `string` name of the class to `$my_child_class_instance`, yet.

Comment: @LauriElias Moreover, the OP's question is about internal class family access, not indirect access, or external access.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you would need to access it like this:

```
self::CONSTANT_1;
```

or alternatively "parent", which will always be the value established in the parent class (i.e., the constant's immutability is maintained):

```
parent::CONSTANT_1;
```

In both parent and children classes, you can use:

```
static::CONSTANT_1;
```

### Interesting

One thing that is interesting to note is that you can actually override the const value in your child class.

```
class MyParentClass{

    const CONSTANT_1=1;
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass{

    const CONSTANT_1=2;
}

echo MyParentClass::CONSTANT_1; // outputs 1
echo MyChildClass::CONSTANT_1; // outputs 2
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how client code can access the class constant. This is a question of visibility in the child class. `self` is the way to go.

Comment: For anyone coming here via google, check out the concept of late static binding. self::CONSTANT and static::CONSTANT yield different results.

Answer (score 10):

You can also access to constant define in children from parent method, with the *static* key.

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function bar() {

        var_dump(static::A);
    }
}

class Baz extends Foo {

    const A = 'FooBarBaz';

    public function __construct() {

        $this->bar();
    }
}

new Baz;
```

Comment: Why 'is the way to go' ? Can you explain ? I see its quite the opposite for example if your abstract class has a method and calling `self` will reference the constant value from the parent while `static` is quite aware of the inheritance and will output the child class value..

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to use `parent`. You can use `self` which would first check if there is `constant` with the same name in the `class` itself, then it would try to access the `parents` `constant`.

So `self` is more versatile and provides the possibility to 'overwrite' the `parents` `constant`, without actually overwriting it as you can still explicitly access it via `parent::`.

Following structure:

```
<?php

class parentClass {

    const MY_CONST = 12;

}

class childClass extends parentClass {

    public function getConst() {
        return self::MY_CONST;
    }

    public function getParentConst() {
        return parent::MY_CONST;
    }

}

class otherChild extends parentClass {

    const MY_CONST = 200;

    public function getConst() {
        return self::MY_CONST;
    }

    public function getParentConst() {
        return parent::MY_CONST;
    }
}
```

Leads to the following results:

```
$childClass = new childClass();
$otherChild = new otherChild();


echo childClass::MY_CONST; // 12
echo otherChild::MY_CONST; // 200

echo $childClass->getConst(); // 12
echo $otherChild->getConst(); // 200

echo $childClass->getParentConst(); // 12
echo $otherChild->getParentConst(); // 12
```

Comment: Of the answers given, using `self` in the child class is the best answer. Note, in PHP 7.1+, you can add visibility modifiers to constants (public, protected, private). Thus, `self` (a reference to the class, *itself*) is more important to understand than ever. Note, though, that the OP question does not concern accessing the constant in client code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class MyParentClass{
    const CONSTANT_1=123;
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass{

    public static function x() {
        echo parent::CONSTANT_1;
    }

}

MyChildClass::x();
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/Yqgyc6MH

Answer (score 0):

Use [parent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php), for example:

```
class MyParentClass{

    const CONSTANT_1=1;
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass{

   function __construct(){
      echo parent::CONSTANT_1;  //here you get access to CONSTANT_1 
   }

}

new MyChildClass();
```

OR:

```
 class MyParentClass{

        const CONSTANT_1=1;
    }

    class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass{

      MyParentClass::CONSTANT_1; // here you you get access to CONSTANT_1 too

    }
```

Comment: ok, so you cannot access them like you would a parent variable e.g. $this->CONSTANT_1?

Comment: how do you mean of course?  If it was as simple as 'of course' I wouldn't be asking.  You a=can access parent variables that way.

Comment: variables, but not a constant and static methods/properties

Comment: well that is precisely what I didn't know.  I knew that about static methods and properties but not constants.

Comment: Nicola, $this is used internally in an object - ie an instance of a class - and refers to the object itself.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `self` keyword.

```
class Whale
{
    const BLOWHOLES = 1;
}

class BlueWhale extends Whale
{ 
    /**
     * A method that does absolutely nothing useful.
     */
    public function funnyCalculation()
    {
        return self::BLOWHOLES + 2;  // This is the access you are looking for.
    }
}
```

Check the PHP manual for [ways to access class constants inside and outside of the class definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).